# If $E(Xi'Xi)$ is invertible and $\Sigma>0$, is $E(Xi'\Sigma^{-1}Xi)$ invertible?

Tags: matrices, statistics

$\Sigma>0$ means that it is a positive definite matrix, and $E$ is simply the expectations operator over observations. Dimensions are correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually there is an additional assumption like $rk(X)=K$ which implies that both $E(X^TX)$ and $E(X^T \Omega^{-1}X)$ are full rank. The empirical averages $E_N(X_i^TX_i)$ and $E_N(X_i^T \Omega^{-1}X_i)$ are invertible provided that $N$ is sufficiently large (by the law of large numbers).